# Regular expression for matching php's constant definition

Tags: c#, php, regex

I wrote a regular expression for matching php's constant definition.

Example:

```
define('Symfony∞DI', SYS_DIRECTORY_PUBLIC . SYS_DIRECTORY_INCLUDES . SYS_DIRECTORY_CLASSES . SYS_DIRECTORY_EXTERNAL . 'symfony/di/');
```

Here is the regular expression:

```
define\((\"|\')+([\w-\.-∞]+)+(\"|\')+(,)+((\s)+(\"|\')+([\w-(\')-\\"-\.-∞-\s-(\\)-\/]+)+(\"|\')|(([\w-\s-\.-∞-(\\)-\/]+)))\);
```

When I executed with ActionScript it works fine. But when I executed with C# it gives me the following error:

```
parsing "define\((\"|\')+([\w-\.-∞]+)+(\"|\')+(,)+((\s)+(\"|\')+([\w-(\')-\\"-\.-∞-\s-(\\)-\/]+)+(\"|\')|(([\w-\s-\.-∞-(\\)-\/]+)))\);" - Cannot include class \s in character range.
```

Could you help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be using regexes in a completely convoluted way:

1. character classes: the `-` is special and it there to compute an interval; I guess you have an ordering inversion which .Net doesn't handle whereas PHP handles it (or maybe the collating order is different in PHP). Your character class should read `[\w.∞]` instead of `[\w-.-∞]`, just to quote the first example;
2. no need to put a group around `\s`: `\s+`, not `(\s)+`; similarly, `,` instead of `(,)`.
3. `'` is not special in a regex, and if you want to match two characters, use a character class, not a group + alternative: `['\"]` instead of `(\'|\")` -- and note that the '"' is escaped only because you are in a doubly quoted string;
4. your regex is not anchored at the beginning and it looks like you want to match `define` at the beginning of the output: `^define` and not `define`.

The 1. is probably the source of your problems.

Rewriting your regex with all of the above gives this (in double quotes):

```
"^define\(([\"'][\w.∞]+[\"'],(\s+[\"']+[\w'\".∞\s\\/]+)+[\"']|([\w\s.∞\\/]+))\);"
```

which definitely doesn't look that it will ever match your input...

Try this instead:

```
"^define\(\s*(['\"])[\w.∞]+\1\s*,\s*([\w/]+(\s*\.\s*[\w/]+)*\s*\);$"
```

Answer (score 1):

See fge's answer for the error you're having. Without knowing what your tring to do and not deviating too much from your original, here is an alternative regex:

`define\(\s*(["'])\s*[\w.∞]+\s*\1(?:\s*[.,]\s*(["']?)\s*[\w/]+\s*\2)*\s*\);`

```
define
\(
  \s* (["'])
  \s* [\w.∞]+
  \s* \1
  (?:
    \s* [.,]
    \s* (["']?)
    \s* [\w/]+
    \s* \2
  )*
  \s*
\);
```